# Home Network VPN solutions for DSL?

Tags: vpn, home-networking, openvpn, dsl

I have a handful of servers and PC's in my home network. I want to set up a VPN so that I can access any of my home network devices while in the office and traveling. To date I have just been using TeamViewer to log into my dev pc and then access and control the other machines remotely through that machine. From the research I have done it seems like the best way to do this is with OpenVPN and installing Tomato on my router but nothing that seemed to specifically match my setup and requirements.

Can someone give me some advice on the best, free, way to set up a VPN for my home network?

My service is AT&T Uverse, its DSL. The router\modem I use is one provided by AT&T, a Motorola NVG589. My network consists of a macbook pro, an iMac, a Media server, a Dev server (poweredge 1950), a Windows 7 dev pc, and a windows 7 laptop. I have also have a personal router\wifi that is not hooked up but could be used if required, it is a TPlink WR841ND I think.

Comment: If you can VPN to the router then problem solved without any additional devices or config. If you're comfortable with putting Tomato onto the router (if it doesn't have its own VPN capabilities) then you can connect from anywhere...

Comment: The router has no native VPN server installed on it. I did not see a tomato firmware specifically for the NVG589 modem\router, which is why I am posting this question. I do any another router but I am unsure if I can install the vpn server onto that and use it in conjunction with the NVG589.